# Replace column value with another column value if condition met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df in which I first split col1 at "-". This results "None" values in col3 if delimiter does not exist in the col1.

Now, if col3 is "None", I want to replace it with col2 values (inplace replacement)

> ```
> #df
>  col1 col2 col3
> 45-65 45 65   
>    56 56 None
>
> #desired df
>  col1 col2 col3
> 45-65 45 65   
>    55 55 55
> ```

How can I do this in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.ffill(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    col1 col2 col3
0  45-65   45   65
1     56   56   56
```